# Simplemodal - how to set focus on an element in onShow function

Tags: jquery, focus, simplemodal

I thought it is going to be simple. Just

```
...
onShow:function(dialog){
   dialog.data.find("input#myInput").focus();
}
...
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a conflict with SimpleModal's focus() function?

I noticed that if i put an alert() inside onShow function it pops before modal is visible. Is there a way to call function (ie. focus()) after displaying modal, but without user input (without user triggering some kind of event)?

Also when i tried to use simplemodal's

```
focus:true
```

with dialog.data =

```
'<div class="myModal login">'+
    '<div class="modalTitle">Title</div>'+
    '<div class="modalContent">'+
       '<label for="username">Login: </label>'+
       '<input id="username" />'+
       '<br />'+
       '<label for="password">Pass: </label>'+
       '<input id="password" type="password" />'+
       '<br />'+
       '<div class="confirmButton no simplemodal-close">Cancel</div>'+
       '<div class="confirmButton yes">Login</div>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>'
```

focus is on wrapper (at least i think so) and user has to press tab to get to first input element.

Any help would be great,

Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onShow:function(dialog){
   setTimeout(function(){
     dialog.data.find("input#myInput").focus();
   },50);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, i had to set it up for 200 to make it work. Your answer was a hint telling me why it didn't work in the first place - i used onOpen function too, with some animations. Once i commented out the whole onOpen function it worked even without setTimeout().